# Raspbian - Forcing monitor to 120 Hz

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, monitors

I have a 165 Hz monitor, and a Rpi 4b. In the raspbian monitor configuration, I can only push my monitor at 60 Hz, but my monitor supports 144 Hz on HDMI.

***For clarity, my question is NOT about my Raspberry Pi, it is about the operating system (Raspbian 10), so this question (probably) should go here, NOT on the Raspberry Pi stackexchange site***

#### I'd like to force my raspberry pi to run my monitor at 120 Hz, but I can't find a way to do so. Is there a way for me to do this?

For context, this is my RPi setup:

**Board**: Raspberry Pi 4b, 8 GB of RAM

**Monitor connection**: Compact HDMI (the HDMI cable that isn't full-size but isn't the smaller size) to full HDMI adapter, connected directly to the board (on connector #0). It's connected to my Acer monitor, which definitely supports 165 Hz (my main Windows device can run it at 165 Hz on DP and my Chromebook can run it at 120 over HDMI, and my monitor's refresh counter agrees with the devices)

**Monitor Resolution**: 1920x1080 at 1080p

Comment: At what resolution? The RPi4 can only do 4K@60fps.

Comment: @Bib 1920x1080 at 1080p... I should probably add that to my question, thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? `xrandr`?

Comment: I've only used the built-in Raspbian display configuration. I even went and tried to find where the monitor configuration file was, but I couldn't find it

Comment: there's no such thing as a monitor configuration file; the monitor identifies its capabilities when asked for it, and then the display system chooses the configuration supported and desired. Not sure the hardware on the Pi could even technically do 120 Hz, but you could try to force it using `xrandr --newmode name mode...`, followed by `xrandr --output <nameofoutput> --addmode name` followed by `xrandr --output <nameofoutput> --mode name`. I have *serious* doubts this does anything useful, however, in a RPi use case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have been fixed in the Debian 11-based Raspbian Pi OS update

Following the manual update instructions, the new KMS driver allows running my monitor at 120 Hz

If you also have this problem you should update too